# Find Sites with Retention Policies?

Tags: retention, information-policy, information-lifecycle-management

Is there a way, maybe through PowerShell or something to find all of the SharePoint sites that have a retention policy applied to document libraries?

Bismarck

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/644e54/generate-file-plan-report-in-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365/) shows how to get a document library level File Plan Report.  I could not find anything that applies to an entire SP Site Collection though.